# Get characters from string - Arduino

Tags: string, arduino

I have the following string:

```
String msg = "t22h58m798s2";
```

Than I created some variables:

```
int temperature;
int humidity;
int moisture;
int state;
```

I need to set value of `temperature` to two numbers after `t` character in `msg`. The same for other variables. Finally `temperature` should be 22, `humidity` - 58, `moisture` - 798 and `state` - 2. I receive `msg` from other Arduino's sensor values. I think I should do it using `indexOf` and `charAt` method, but I'm not sure how. Please hep me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substring function in arduino to a string from a particular character to another one. Like in this particular case you can use something like 
String temperature= msg.substring("1, 3");

Refer this for more information.
http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringSubstring